# Error loading oracle libraries

Tags: oracle, debian, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I installed oracle 12 in debian and i have a problem with the shared libraries
Can someone give me the contents of the file 'libclntsh.so.12.1' ?
Can someone help me ?
thanks in advance

Comment: If your installation failed, as you said in a comment on an answer, then you should find out what the error was and fix that. Copying files from somewhere else isn't a good idea - if the options used for installation don't match you will have odd errors, for a start, and I doubt Oracle would see that as a supportable environment. The only reason I can think you'd get a zero-byte file when linking is if you ran out of space on that filesystem, but check the logs to see what really happened.

Comment: Thanks Alex that was the problem and i solved it by relinking the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to find 'libclntsh.so'
find / -name "libclntsh.so*"
Maybe you can do a soft link to libclntsh.so

Possibly you should to specify `PATH` — and also `ORACLE_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` — so that binary knows where to find binaries.
Something like

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/lib/
```

Comment: i already specified the library path
the file "libclntsh.so" is empty

Comment: @ganiamine - if the file is empty you installation may have failed, did you get errors? The linking phase might not have worked for some reason.

Comment: Yes i had an error while the installation
is there any solution ?

Comment: @gani amine is distributed and bunch of object files `.o`. These are linked during installation. Most probably this link operation failed on Debian. Use relink tool and then check output from compilation.